# Openning hyperlinks in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

In my jupyter notebook I have a pandas dataframe with a column that has HTML hyperlinks such as

```py
<a href='data_exploration.html'>data_exploration</a>
```

I convert the data frame using to_html() and I use the Ipython function HTML to display the data frame on my notebook, however, when I click on the link it returns a 404 page not found does anyone have experience with this that can help

- The path in the anchor tag is a relative path from the base directory.

Comment: Is the base directory where the file resides and the base directory of the notebook different? What is the URL you get when you click on the link?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("data_exploration.html")
```

this code will directly open the data_exploration file as URL in your browser